# How to have ros1_bridge handle external package name change?

Tags: ros, ros2, gps-common

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use ros1_bridge to handle bridging a topic which uses the gps_common/GPSFix message. In ROS2 the gps_common package was renamed to gps_msgs. With ros1_bridge you normally handle that with a rule.yaml file exported by the ROS2 package. However, since these packages are pulled in with apt I can't add the file directly to gps_msgs. Would I need to build these messages from source? Or is there a solution which doesn't require as much change to my dependency management?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396713/how-to-have-ros1_bridge-handle-external-package-name-change?/) by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2022-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well is seems the rule file is actually available as part of the gps_msgs distribution. https://github.com/swri-robotics/gps_umd/blob/dashing-devel/gps_msgs/ros1_ros2_mapping.yaml

It seems I missed it before. The failure to link must be caused by a separate issue. I will close this question.

---

Originally posted by [msmcconnell](https://answers.ros.org/users/30781/msmcconnell/) with karma: 268 on 2022-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0